# GDAL 3.4.1 build "Cannot create TIFF file due to missing codec for DEFLATE"

Tags: linux, installation, build, gdal

I have built GDAL 3.4.1 on CentOS7.  Everything seems to be working except if I try to use DEFLATE compression and I get the error below.  I have installed libtiff-4.1.0 and libdeflate-1.10.  Previously I was running GDAL 2.3.2 using a similar build process with no issues with DEFLATE.

Can anyone suggest what I may be missing to get DEFLATE compression working?  Thanks!

```
gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE /cmake-3.19.5/Packaging/CMakeDMGBackground.tif test.tif
Input file size is 500, 365
Warning 6: 'DEFLATE' is an unexpected value for COMPRESS creation option of type string-select.
ERROR 1: Cannot create TIFF file due to missing codec for DEFLATE.
```

My GDAL build output shows:

```
checking for deflateInit_ in -lz... no
using internal libz code as deflateInit_ is missing
using internal libz code.
checking for libdeflate_zlib_decompress in -ldeflate... yes
checking libdeflate.h usability... yes
checking libdeflate.h presence... yes
checking for libdeflate.h... yes
...
  libdeflate support:        yes
  LIBGEOTIFF support:        internal
  LIBGIF support:            internal
  LIBJPEG support:           internal
  LIBLZMA support:           no
  LIBPNG support:            internal
  LIBTIFF support:           external (BigTIFF=yes)
  libxml2 support:           no
  LIBZ support:              internal
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I did not have zlib installed.  Installing zlib fixed my issue.